# Draw Horizontal line between rows in latex table

Tags: tables, rules

i want to draw horizontal lines between rows in the table.

I have tried like this so far,

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    attribute& Art. 16.1.b\&c Aggregated generation per type\\
    \hline
     DocumentType& A75:actual generation per type A74:wind and solar generation\\
     ProcessType& A16:realised\\
     In\_Domain& Used\\
     PsrType& May be used\\
     TimeInterval& Used\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
```

This output i am getting [image]

Expected output link

https://ibb.co/89dBZGN

Thanks got the expected result:

Answer:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    attribute& Art. 16.1.b\&c Aggregated generation per type\\
    \hline
     DocumentType& A75:actual generation per type A74:wind and solar generation\\
     \hline
     ProcessType& A16:realised\\
     \hline
     In\_Domain& Used\\
     \hline
     PsrType& May be used\\
     \hline
     TimeInterval& Used\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding additional `\hline` commands?

Comment: @chrisma yes i have got the result after using the `\hline`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Additional horizontal lines can be added by using the `\hline` command between rows, just as the top and bottom lines were added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    attribute& Art. 16.1.b\&c Aggregated generation per type\\
    \hline
    DocumentType& A75:actual generation per type A74:wind and solar generation\\
    \hline
    ProcessType& A16:realised\\
    \hline
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX]

Comment: `\hline` must be preceded by double backslash except the first one. However, I omitted the last \\